# Как использовать чужой открытый WebSocket?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket

Есть одна JavaScript игра, с обфусцированным кодом, которая создаёт WebSocket соединение.
Мне бы хотелось как-то слать данные через это WebSocket соединение, ввиду обфусцированности кода, просто залезть в него и посмотреть что-то не самая лучшая идея.

Какие могут быть способы это сделать? Браузер: Google Chrome.

Comment: Не стоит задавать несколько одинаковых вопросов. Лучше внести правку в предыдущий.

Comment: А зачем именно через это соединение? Создайте еще одно, такое же - и отправляйте... или воспользуйтесь фидлером

Comment: насколько я знаю - к чужому открытому никак. Можно разве что поставить штуку которая будет ловить трафик. Это типо аля VPN, но он будет просеивать трафик и нужные Вам данные. Но если есть https то не получится. Другой вариант написать свою утилиту которая будет делать тоже самое что и их, только с Вашими штуками.